# Apache htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like - 
`http://www.mydomain.com/website/dev/main/html/about_us.html`

How can I rewrite it to simply `http://www.mydomain.com/about` ?

I have seen many examples of URL rewrite on internet and SO but still couldn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want everything redirected to /about?

Comment: @radashk Not everything. For example - `http://www.mydomain.com/website/dev/main/html/contact_us.html` should get redirected to `http://www.mydomain.com/contact` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess, make sure that mod_rewrite is actuvated on your server:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^about$ ./website/dev/main/html/about_us.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is a repeat of an existing question. Make sure you have in your file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about$ website/dev/main/html/about_us.html
```

You can also pass vars this way too:

```
RewriteRule ^about/(.+)/(.+)$ about/index.php?q=$1&p=$2
```

Where `about/12/23` would equal `about/index.php?q=12&p=23`

Answer (score 1):

Working from the Apache [Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html), your .htaccess file should contain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/about$ ./website/dev/main/html/about_us.html [R]
```

That turns the rewrite engine on (if it isn't already) and then sets up a rule.  Any URL after the domain that matches the regex `^/about$` will be redirected transparently to `/website/dev/main/html/about_us.html`